# INSERT INTO syntax

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a textbox on a form, it contains number and query has value in it.

I need Access VBA code doing that, when I press button save it takes the the textbox content and the query value and save it in table in 2 various columns, using `insert into`.

I tried this:

```vb
docmd.runsql "insert into reqCount(dailyrec, driverid) values ("&txtreq&","Select driverid from getdriverdata");"
```

But it's not working.

Comment: Should be something like `insert into td (c1, c2) select ... from ...`.

Comment: Yes, it's like that I need the right syntax

Comment: SELECT query mus be encloses in parentheses and result should be concatenated into the INSERT INTO statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
CurrentDb.Execute "insert into reqCount (dailyrec, driverid) Select '" & Me!txtreq.Value & "', driverid from getdriverdata;"
```

Comment: wow its working thank you (Gustav) many thanks its over one week i searching for this code thx alot.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "INSERT INTO reqCount (dailyrec, driverid) SELECT " & txtreq & ", driverid FROM getdriverdata;"
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?